# Python - Define the disk size of a pdf page

Tags: python, pdf

I am currently writing a python script, that sends a pdf to an API online.

This API limits incoming files to 4MB, and i sometimes have pdf files larger than that.

To solve this, my idea was that when a pdf larger than 4MB is encountered, i check the pages inside one by one, to constitute a smaller pdf. After that, i only have to reassemble what the API returns to have my file processed.

I found code to check the physical size of a page, or of its individual elements, but nothing about the disk usage itself.

Has anyone done this before ? My only other solution would be to split a pdf into its constituing pages when larger than 4MB, but that sounds suboptimal.

Thanks

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed SI units. Upper case M=mega. Lower case m=milli. Upper case B=byte. Lower case b=bit. Therefore `MB`=megabyte and `mb` is looking like a millibit - whatever that is.

Comment: you are correct. I'll update this

Comment: There can be no guarantee that every individual page will be less than 4 MB.

Comment: PDFs contain many shared resources like images and fonts. If you thoughts are that each page summed together = the whole, that is likely wrong.

Comment: @tripleee Yeah, i know that theorically a page can have images and things over 4MB, i'm just trying to find a solution :( In my use case, a pdf would be huge because it was scanned in a high resolution, so *logically* each page weighs about the same.